# R: 3d plot of matrix against matrix

Tags: r

Let us consider the following codes:

```
x=seq(1,30,1)
t=runif(10)

z_t=array(0,dim=c(10,30))

for (i in 1:10){
for (j in 1:30){
z_t[i,j]=x[j]+x[j]*t[i]
}
}
```

How to plot(t,x,z_t) where t is a vector of dimension 10, x is a vector of dimension 30 and z_t is matrix of dimension (10x30)?

Comment: I sorted the issue. By taking the equispaced gridded values of t=seq(min(t),max(t),length.out=10), one can just use the persp(t,x,z_t) and get surface plot. I was missing previously that the persp function needed ordered arguments as x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure whether this is the plot you are looking for, but try playing around with plotly library.

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(z = z_t,  type = "surface")
```

Comment: Thanks for your try. This function is not considering the values of x and t in the x axis and y axis. So it interpretation in not clear to me now.